# Checking duplicate for multidimensional arrays (3rd level)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 3 levels of multi dimensional arrays and I wanted to check for duplicates and only should return true or false. I tried doing the `array_unique()` but I think this one only works for single level array. My array looks like this:

```
array(
   0 => array(
               0=> array(
                          0=> "A"
                          1=> "B"
                          2=> "C"
                        )
               1=> array(
                          0=> "D"
                          1=> "E"
                          2=> "F"
                        )
               2=> array(
                          0=> "G"
                          1=> "H"
                          2=> "I"
                        )
               3=> array(
                          0=> "A"
                          1=> null
                          2=> null
                        )
             )

)
```

the expected result should be that "A" is already duplicated and should return true ,otherwise should be false. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten your array using `RecursiveArrayIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator`. To check if there are duplicates, you can check the count of flattened array vs the count unique values of the flattened array.

```
$arr = //Your array
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
foreach($it as $v) $result[] = $v;

if ( count( $result ) !== count( array_unique( $result ) ) ) {
    echo "Duplicate"; //Return true
} else {
    echo "No Duplicate";
}
```

Comment: does this count the "null" values as duplicated as well?

Comment: @kevin_marcus Yes. Should be null counted?

Comment: Actually no need. I put a condition where in if value is not equal to null then I will pass the value to the array result. This answer helped me a lot. thanks bud!